# loop through multidimensional array php - get all index and implode to string

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am stuck with a part of my code and i can't see to figure out why i get a certain result. What my goal is to loop through the array and echo this result as a string:

**First Array**

1. validate.required
2. validate.remote

**Second array**

shop.cart.string

Current result is:

1. validate.0.required
2. validate.1.remote

It returns the index from the array, how can solve this/remove this from my string?

```
  private $translationKeys = [
    'validate' => [
      'required',
      'remote',
      'email',
      'url',
      'date',
      'dateISO',
      'number',
      'digits',
      'creditcard',
      'equalTo',
      'extension',
      'maxlength',
      'minlength',
      'rangelength',
      'range',
      'max',
      'min',
      'step'
    ],
    'shop' => [
        'cart' => [
         'string'
        ],
    ],
];
```

​
This is my function:

```
function listArrayRecursive($translationKeys) {
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($translationKeys), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
  if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
  } else {
    for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
      $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
      $y = array();
      foreach ($p as $value) {
        array_push($y, $value);
      }
    }
    $path = implode('.', $y); 
    $a[] = "$path.$v<br>";
    // Here i want to echo the string
  }
}
```

}

Second version of the function

```
  function listArrayRecursive($translationKeys) {
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($translationKeys), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
  if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
  } else {
    for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
      $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
    }
    $path = implode('.', $p); 
    $a[] = "$path.$v<br>";
  }
}
```

}

Comment: What is `$a`? all you want is the inner path to all object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will give you the result you desire. It recurses through each element of the array that is an array, concatenating the key with the values, or just returns the value if it is not an array:

```
function listArrayRecursive($array) {
    $list = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach (listArrayRecursive($value) as $v) {
                $list[] = "$key.$v";
            }
        }
        else {
            $list[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
print_r(listArrayRecursive($translationKeys));
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => validate.required
    [1] => validate.remote
    [2] => validate.email
    [3] => validate.url
    [4] => validate.date
    [5] => validate.dateISO
    [6] => validate.number
    [7] => validate.digits
    [8] => validate.creditcard
    [9] => validate.equalTo
    [10] => validate.extension
    [11] => validate.maxlength
    [12] => validate.minlength
    [13] => validate.rangelength
    [14] => validate.range
    [15] => validate.max
    [16] => validate.min
    [17] => validate.step
    [18] => shop.cart.string 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vKm1c)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
function disp_array_rec($arr, $upper = null) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        echo ($upper != null ? $upper : "");
        if (is_array($v)) {
            disp_array_rec($v, $k . ".");
        } else {
            echo "$v\n";
        }
    }
}

disp_array_rec($translationKeys);
```

result:

```
validate.required
validate.remote
validate.email
validate.url
validate.date
validate.dateISO
validate.number
validate.digits
validate.creditcard
validate.equalTo
validate.extension
validate.maxlength
validate.minlength
validate.rangelength
validate.range
validate.max
validate.min
validate.step
shop.cart.string
```